# Redirect Each Page of Old Domain to Same Page URL on the New Domain

Tags: linux, .htaccess, redirect, seo

I know this question has been asked with all variations but I still cannot find the exact answer. I have changed my domain name. All website files and urls are still the same. old domain still points so the same server and I have the following code in htaccess file.

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^olddomain\.com$ [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.olddomain\.com$
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "https\:\/\/www\.newdomain\.com\/$1" [R=301,L]
```

Problem is that this only redirects the old domain home page. What can I do so I don't have to add individual redirects for each page.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about **SEO** which is off-topic at Stack Overflow. Please read ["Which SEO questions should be closed as non-programming/non-admin?"](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/382618) to better understand when SEO questions are acceptable to ask here (most are not) and where you might be able to get assistance.

Comment: Just because I chose SEO as a tag, it does not make this an SEO question. Why are there a bunch of htaccess questions here then?

Comment: You really should click on the link in my comment and read its contents

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you've put these directives in the wrong place in your `.htaccess` file. They need to go at the beginning of the file, not at the end.

These directives look typical of cPanel generated redirects. cPanel always places redirects at the end of the `.htaccess` file (which is often incorrect).

If you have a front-controller before this (such as that used by WordPress) then you will find that these directives will only get processed for requests to the document root (ie. the "homepage"), as all other requests will be stopped by the front-controller.

These directives can also be simplified:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?olddomain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I've removed the `$` from the end of the *CondPattern* so as to match a FQDN (that ends in a dot).

There is also no need to backslash escape colons, slashes and dots in the `RewriteRule` *substitution*, as these characters carry no special meaning here (it's not a regex). (This unnecessary escaping is very typical of cPanel.)

Comment: I had solved this already by moving those directives to the beginning of the file before the wordpress default code in there. I'll apply the other changes you suggested also. Thank you so much for the reply, This is the correct answer!